# Refresh data Ajax when Click Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get/refresh data using ajax when click button, here is what i'm trying so far :

HTML

```
<button class="btn-area" data-id="1">Area 1</button>
<button class="btn-area" data-id="2">Area 2</button>
<div id="mapdiv"></div>
```

Javascript

```
//API URL default
var url = "/api/division/" + {{ $division->id }};

//Data for Map
var dataMap = [];

//Options For Map
var options = {
type: "map",
dataProvider: {
    map: "worldLow",
    getAreasFromMap: true,
    zoomLevel: 0.9,
    images: dataMap //Data for Map
},
};

// Run map
AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", options, dataMap);
```

When i click the button, data from ajax show in console, but data for map still empty

```
//Run ajax request from button
$(".btn-area").click(function(e) {
var areaId = $(this).attr("data-id");
var url = "/api/division/" + {{$division->id}} + "/" + areaId;
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dataMap.push({
           "latitude": data[i].cor_x,
           "longitude": data[i].cor_y,
         });
        }
        console.log(dataMap); //test in console
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
});
```

Server code using laravel

```
//Route SiteController.php
public function getSiteByDivision($idDiv)
{
    $sites = Site::where(['division_id' => $idDiv])->get();
    return $sites;
}
public function getSiteByDivisionArea($idDiv,$idArea)
{
    $sites = Site::where(['division_id' => $idDiv,'area_id' => $idArea])->get();
    return $sites;
}

//Route api.php
Route::get('division/{idDiv}','SiteController@getSiteByDivision');
Route::get('division/{idDiv}/{idArea}','SiteController@getSiteByDivisionArea');
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Show the server code dude

Comment: server code added, thanks

Comment: have you checked that data actually holds data?

Comment: Are you saying that when you run // Run map
AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", options, dataMap); <----- dataMap is empty here?